# '-*' appearing in assembly output

Tags: assembly, masm, uppercase, lowercase, irvine32

I'm writing a program that will take a string and output the original string, a version of the string that is all lowercase, and a version of the string that is all uppercase. For some reason, though, the output looks like this:

```
Assembly is kinda fun
assembly is kinda fun-*
ASSEMBLY IS KINDA FUN
```

I can't figure out why the '-*' is appearing after the lowercase output, especially since it's virtually identical to the uppercase output. Can someone please shed some light as to why this is happening? Here's my code:

```
TITLE MASM Template                     (main.asm)

; Description:
; 
; Revision date: 4/12/16

INCLUDE Irvine32.inc
.data
myString BYTE "Assembly is kinda fun", 0dh, 0ah, 0
myOtherString BYTE 70 DUP(?), 0dh, 0ah, 0
.code

main PROC
call Clrscr
MOV EDX, OFFSET myString
Call WriteString
LEA ESI, myString

MOV ECX, 70
copyloop1:
    MOV AL, [ESI]
    OR AL, 00100000b
    MOV myOtherString, AL
    MOV EDX, OFFSET myOtherString
    Call WriteChar
    INC ESI
LOOP copyloop1
CALL Crlf
LEA ESI, myString
MOV ECX, 70
copyloop2:
    MOV AL, [ESI]
    AND AL, 11011111b
    MOV myOtherString, AL
    MOV EDX, OFFSET myOtherString
    Call WriteChar
    INC ESI
LOOP copyloop2
CALL Crlf
exit
main ENDP

END main
```

Comment: Bit arithmetic quiz: what is 0dh OR 00100000b?  How about 0ah OR 00100000b?

Comment: @NateEldredge 00101101 and 00101010 ... Ohhhhhhhhh thank you lol

Comment: Which is the ASCII code for ... ?

Comment: @NateEldredge thank you haha I can't believe I let that slip over my head!

Comment: The CPU is sending you a kiss emoticon, because you are having fun with assembly.

Answer (score 2):

Your string `myString` ends in `0dh,0ah` (CR LF).  To convert characters to lower case, your code ORs them with 00100000b (20h).  You also do this to the CR LF, resulting in characters `2dh,2ah` which are `-*`.

To convert to upper case, you AND with 11011111b.  This converts `-*` back to CR LF, so you don't see the funny characters in the upper-case printout.